# How to optimise tables in Netezza to compliment a join with date conditions

Tags: date, join, netezza

I have two tables that I need to join in Netezza and one of them is very large

I have a dimension table that is a customer table which has two fields, customer id and an observation date i.e.

```
cust_id, obs_date
'a','2015-01-05'
'b','2016-02-03'
'c','2014-05-21'
'd','2016-01-31'
```

I have a fact table that is transactional and very high in volume. It has a lot of transactions per customer per date i.e.

```
cust_id, tran_date, transaction_amt
'a','2015-01-01',1
'a','2015-01-01',2
'a','2015-01-01',5
'a','2015-01-02',7
'a','2015-01-02',2
'b','2016-01-02',12
```

Both tables are distributed by the same key - cust_id

However When I join the tables, i need to join given the date condition. The query is very fast when i just join them together, but when I add the date condition it does not seem optimised. Does anyone have tips on how to set up the underlying tables or write the join?

I.e. sum transaction_amt for each customer for all their transactions for the 3 months up to their obs_date

```
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
INNER JOIN TRANSACTION_TABLE
ON CUSTOMER_TABLE.cust_id = TRANSACTION_TABLE.cust_id
  AND TRANSACTION_TABLE.TRAN_DATE BETWEEN CUSTOMER_TABLE.OBS_DATE - 30   AND CUSTOMER_TABLE.OBS_DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

If your transaction table is sufficiently large, it may benefit from using [CBTs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/c_sysadm_selecting_org_keys.html).

If you can, create a copy of the table that uses `TRAN_DATE` to organize (I'm guessing at your ddl here):

```
create table transaction_table (
  cust_id varchar(20)
  ,tran_date date
  ,transaction_amt numeric(10,0)
) distribute on (cust_id)
organize on (tran_date);
```

Join to that and see if performance is improved. You could also use a materialized view for just those columns, but I think a CBT would be more useful here.

As Scott mentions in the comments below, you should either sort by the date on insert or groom the records after to make sure that they are sorted appropriately.

Comment: Perhaps also mention the initial groom records all required after the cut definition.

Comment: I was talking about creating another copy of the table; but yes, if you reorganize instead of create/insert, you'll need to groom the records. If the  table is large enough, copying it may be prohibitive.

Comment: Even if you do the create/insert, you will either need to groom or sort when you do the insert in order to get the zone map benefits though.

Comment: I understand. You're absolutely right. A cbt wouldn't sort otherwise.